# How is a variable passed to theme_hook (theme_item_list, FacetAPI)

Tags: search, theming

**Problem**

I'm trying to register a new theme function based off `theme_item_list` to alter the display of a facet.

`Theme_item_list` is passed in an array `$variables`. Crucially I can't work out how the facetAPI passes the variables needed for `theme_item_list` to render a list. It sets up the array in the `execute` method of `FacetapiWidgetLinks` and somehow successfully passes this to `theme_item_list` but I can't get my own theme function to receive anything.

How does `theme_item_list` receive it's `$variables` array?

**More Information**

*Code altered thanks to kiamlaluno*

I currently have the following code in my module:

```
function my_module_theme($variables) {
  return array(
    'item_list_aggregate' => array('variables' => array(
      'items' => array(),
      'attributes' => array(),
      'title' => NULL,
      'type' => 'ul', 
  )));
}

//this is correctly called but $variables is empty
function theme_item_list_aggregate($variables) {
  $items = $variables['items'];
  $title = $variables['title'];
  $type = $variables['type'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  ...
```

`#items` and `#attributes` values are set in the `execute` method below.

They are correctly passed to `theme_item_list` because I can't get them to pass to my theme function, `theme_item_list_aggregate`, the `$variables` variable in `my_module_theme` is empty.

```
class FacetapiWidgetLinks extends FacetapiWidget {

...

public function execute() {
    $element = &$this->build[$this->facet['field alias']];
    $this->setThemeHooks($element);

    // Here I call my own theme function. It's identical
    // to theme_item_list at the moment but my own theme function
    // never gets passed the $element array.
    if(strpos($this->facet['field alias'],"aggregation") != FALSE) {
      $element = array(
        '#theme' => 'item_list_aggregate',
        '#items' => $this->buildListItems($element),
        '#attributes' => $this->build['#attributes'],
      );
    } else {
      $element = array(
        '#theme' => 'item_list',
        '#items' => $this->buildListItems($element),
        '#attributes' => $this->build['#attributes'],
      );
    }
  }

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a new theme function. You could use the existing theme_item_list and extend it with double underscore. Rename `item_list_aggregate` to `item_list__aggregate` in `FacetapiWidgetLinks::execute`. And implement `theme_item_list` and theme_item_list__aggregate in your theme.

Look at `node_title_list` in core, this function uses the same pattern.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! I'm not entirely sure why it works, but it does definitely work.

Comment: The fallback logic is in [theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) (Comment, If there's no implementation, check for more generic fallbacks ...)

Answer (score 0):

The `hook_theme()` implementation is wrong: The first argument passed to the hook is not the list of the variables to pass to the theme function. Your hook should be implemented with code similar to the following one.

```
function my_module_theme($variables) {
  return array(
    'item_list_aggregate' => array('variables' => array(
      'items' => 'default value for the variable',
      'title' => 'default value for the variable',
      'type' => 'default value for the variable', 
      'attibutes' => 'default value for the variable',
  )));
}
```

For a list of parameters passed to `hook_theme()` see [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). Keep in mind that most `hook_theme()` implementation don't use them.

Comment: Ah so that is a problem, but maybe I explained my original problem badly. The problem is I can't work out how to get the default value for `items` and `attributes` to pass to the theme function. They're set in the `execute` method above and `theme_item_list` receives them in `$variables` but my implementation `theme_item_list_aggregate` doesn't.